# Can't dump a remote database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, rake

I have this database configuration in database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: oma_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

test:
  # same as in development section

production:
  # same as in development section


development_blacklist:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: webstuff
  username: login
  password: password
  host: remote-database.com

test_blacklist:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: webstuff
  username: megas
  password:
  host: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

And I want to execute rake task:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :schema do
    desc 'Dump blacklist database schema'
    task :dump => [:environment, :load_config] do
      filename = "#{Rails.root}/db/blacklist_schema.rb"
      File.open(filename, 'w:utf-8') do |file|
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("development_blacklist")
        ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump(ActiveRecord::Base.connection, file)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

By invoking this command:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

And I've got error:

```
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

So it seems that rake task is trying to connect to database from `development` section.

I don't understand why the rake task is trying to connect to `development` database while the rake task should connect to `development_blacklist` database.

How to setup rake task to connect only to `development_blacklist` database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly set environment, for example:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:dump
```

Comment: Or `RAILS_ENV=development_blacklist rake db:schema:dump` in your case